# GWT HTMLTable colaspan feature

Tags: java, gwt

Hello all
I am using HTMLTable of import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable
I instantiated it like below:

```
HTMLTable table = new Grid(rows, col);
```

Number of rows and columns are decided by the user input.
Now I want to used colspan for the specific rows of the table.

One way to this is apply css to the that specific row.But problem with this is that Number of column to span are decided by the user input, i.e It may vary every time. So by using css it is something like making it static.

So I want to know the way through which I can do colspan on the rows of the table.
and Number of column to span is different every time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try

```
table.getCellFormatter().setAttr(row, col, "colspan", numColsToSpan.toString());
```

Comment: But the setAttr is an protected method of the CellFormatter class which is also inner class of the Row Formatter

Comment: @SanjayJain So why did you accept this answer, if it didn't help you?